# Android Studio emulator (AVD) on Mac OSX : AVD icon quickly appears and immediately disappears

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to launch an AVD in Android Studio on Mac OSX. I create it and then I launch it.

The problem is that the AVD icon quickly appears in the dock and immediately disappears.

Note that the default emulators present in Android Studio work properly.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't create AVD correctly. Try that: Nexus 5x with Marshmallow x86_64 OS. I'm using that emulator and works perfectly.